# Punctuating "etc." after a series of questions

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations

How should I terminally punctuate *etc.* when it's used at the end of a series of questions?

> How's your brother? Did you get the job? Are you feeling better? **Etc.?**

Is this right, or do I use a period?

> How's your brother? Did you get the job? Are you feeling better? **Etc.**

Comment: Regardless of grammar, if someone wrote *etc.* after a personal question, I'd take it to mean they weren't that interested in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Each question is a separate sentence. The Etc. also forms its own sentence, but isn't a question in itself, so I would go for the second one:

> How's your brother? Did you get the job? Are you feeling better? Etc.

A better option may be to rewrite to avoid the etc. altogether.

This answer is with British English. It may be the same with American English.

Answer (score 1):

"Etc." isn't a question. Here, it indicates "and other similar questions." Thus, no question mark is needed.